# How do I create diagonal checher like shape

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to create a diagonal checker grid like this [image: this]

but all I could do with arrray modifire and some tinkering is this:

[image]

I need as clean topology as possible, how can model it in blender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand, but something like this?

[image]

where the base object (in red square) is Z-rotated 45° and rotation applied.

Answer (score 3):

m.arditos way Is legit, but You can also do it like this:[image]